# How to send FCM notification using football api React native Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, express, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am creating a football app using react native and nodejs. I have 1 million users in my mongodb database. Every user can follow there desired team and they will get notified by football events updates like match started, goal scored, match ended etc... of their following teams. I am using Firebase messaging service to send notification. But I don't have any idea how to sent notification to large number of users. All I know is to call football api every minute to get fixture updates. after that i am very confused.

I have discussed about this issue with many developers. But didn't get desired result.
Please someone explain to me. How it's done?

Comment: what API are you using? Would expect them to have support for webhooks - i.e you put in a URL of a serverless/firebase function (that you control). When an event happens (e.g match starts), the football API calls that webhook and your systems then receive that data and you can do whatever you want with it (e.g send a notification with firebase messaging to users). if you want any more info you will need to provide some code of what you've already tried.

Comment: Please use universal measurements instead of local words like *lakh* that not everyone will understand

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about sending messages to a large number of devices. If you know how to [send a message to one device ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-specific-devices), you can just repeat that process until you've sent the message to all device IDs.

If you prefer, you can use [multicast messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-multiple-devices) to send the message to up to 500 device IDs at once. So you will still need a loop to handle all device IDs, but you'll need fewer iterations.

The final alternative would be to [subscribe each device to the same topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic), and then [send a message to that topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-topics) from your server. Behind the scenes this ends up being quite similar, but now the Firebase servers take care of mapping from the topic to the device IDs - so you won't have to do that yourself.